# Conda skeleton pypi fails with pmdarima -- AttributeError numpy disutils

Tags: python, numpy, conda, pypi, pmdarima

I'm trying to install pmdarima package in a conda env as it requires statsmodels <0.12 and I would also like to use statmodels latest release for this project. My understanding is limited, but I first tried

`conda skeleton pypi pmdarima`

This failed with the same AttributeError related to numpy disutils described below.

Similarly to the questioner in this question: [Conda skeleton pypi: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649808/conda-skeleton-pypi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy) I was unable to get this to work either.

`conda install -n _build numpy`

I then tried the advice laid out in the above-linked SO question and ran:

`conda skeleton pypi --extra-specs numpy pmdarima`

This results in pretty long output but the key piece as far as I can tell is:

```
Applying patch: '/var/folders/7f/8d7rz34522gcq4z774n9v91r0000gn/T/tmp8tv1gdnxconda_skeleton_pmdarima-1.7.1.tar.gz/pypi-distutils.patch'
patching file core.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 168 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
Partial import of pmdarima during the build process.
Requirements: ['joblib>=0.11', 'Cython>=0.29,<0.29.18', 'numpy>=1.17.3', 'pandas>=0.19', 'scikit-learn>=0.22', 'scipy>=1.3.2', 'statsmodels>=0.11,<0.12', 'urllib3', 'setuptools<50.0.0']
Setting up with numpy.distutils.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 324, in <module>
    do_setup()
  File "setup.py", line 320, in do_setup
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 130, in setup
    if dist.help or not _command_line_ok():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'help'
$PYTHONPATH = /var/folders/7f/8d7rz34522gcq4z774n9v91r0000gn/T/tmp8tv1gdnxconda_skeleton_pmdarima-1.7.1.tar.gz/pmdarima-1.7.1

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/work 
  Test:
 /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/test_tmp 
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place 
  Build:
source activate  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/_build_env 


Error: command failed: /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1599410605346/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_/bin/python setup.py install
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much in advance, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the proper resolution is for the NumPy-based build, but [the `setup.py` does check for an `sdist` argument](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/blob/v1.7.1/setup.py#L305), which branches to use `setuptools` for the build instead of `numpy`. Hence, the following seems to avoid the code causing the issue:

```
conda skeleton pypi --setup-options sdist pmdarima
```

I suspect the downside to this workaround is that there is no Cython compilation done, but not totally sure.

You may want to [file an issue on the pmdarima GitHub](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/issues) to see if any of the devs have ideas. Otherwise, it might just be more efficient to `pip install` the package in the environment you want it (as long as that environment is not **base**).

Comment: To the extent you are interested there is an existing thread that I asked on, and thought I'd share the fairly detailed and useful response for future reference: https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/issues/326

Answer (score 0):

@merv thank you for your help! Interestingly, this works for the skeleton, but fails when running conda-build with the following (truncated until the errors) output:

```
0 location(s) to search for versions of sdist:
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'sdist': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sdist (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sdist
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 325, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 339, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self._populate_link(req)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 305, in _populate_link
    req.link = self._find_requirement_link(req)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 270, in _find_requirement_link
    best_candidate = self.finder.find_requirement(req, upgrade)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 928, in find_requirement
    req)
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for sdist
Removed build tracker: '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-umxriyi2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 474, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 465, in execute
    verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 210, in build
    notest=notest, variants=variants)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3036, in build_tree
    notest=notest,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2155, in build
    cwd=src_dir, stats=build_stats)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 407, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 387, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/pmdarima_1599500058832/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I'll confess we're well above my head at this point, (do I need to edit the meta.yaml file somehow? Is that crazy?) but will try opening an issue as you suggested, once again really appreciate it.